# How can I send information from a Kinect to an Arduino?

Tags: c#, arduino, kinect, processing

I would like to have my Arduino respond to information taken from my Kinect.  In detail, I want my Arduino to activate certain relays depending on the coordinate location of joints taken by the Kinect.

I'm using C# to run the Kinect and Processing to run the Arduino.  It is possible to run the Kinect with Processing, but I'd rather not take that route because I'll have to use wrappers and other messy things.

I'm running all this on a Windows 7 machine, since the Kinect SDK is only for Windows 7, but I also have Windows XP and Ubuntu 12 machines to use.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Edit: solved it myself!  Used SerialPorts in C# to communicate with the Arduino.  Also had to write a program for the Arduino to process data sent by the PC.

Comment: You can use the usb serial connection the Arduino provides. Have a "server" application on the computer read from the Kinect and dump the relevant data into the serial connection.

Comment: That sounds good, but will this work with real-time data?  Continuously processing data from the Kinect and sending it to the Arduino?

Comment: @Tyrone well, you can't really do anything else... USB is fast.

Comment: Maybe my question was too vague.  I am using USB, but was trying to get the software to work.  I did find my answer myself though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB connection/SDK allows the pc to read the connect and also the same windows program can create a serial connection to an arduino. You can send a stream of data to the arduino that is near enouh real-time.

You don't need to send much to the arduino. For example you might assign a 1 byte id to each joint 0,1,2,3,4 etc and then maybe just a simple value to represent the degree of movement.

In this example 0 represents a hand and 1 a knee...

```
0,180
0,90
1,45
```

This is a good article about interfacing C# serial with the arduino to send your real-time stream

http://jtoee.com/2009/02/talking-to-an-arduino-from-net-c/

Comment: I ran into this solution at the same time you posted, but yes, it does work! Thanks!